# Python and Statsmodels: How to evaluate the F-test of joint parameters in ARMA model?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have an ARMA model like this (it is actually a AR(4) model):

```
arRes4=sm.tsa.ARMA(res2AR, (4,0),freq='Q').fit()
```

with 5 parameters. The code above is working well.

I have tried several possibilities to evaluate the f_test and it is not clear for me it is not working:

```
hypothesis = '(ar.L1.y = 0),(ar.L2.y = 0),(ar.L3.y = 0),(ar.L4.y = 0)'

fTest=arRes4.f_test(hypothesis)
```

It raises the error:

```
    raise ValueError('need covariance of parameters for computing '
ValueError: need covariance of parameters for computing F statistics
```

It is not clear why it asks for the covariance matrix. However, I tried

fTest=arRes4.f_test(hypothesis,arRes4.cov_params().as_matrix())

It raises the error

```
    cov_p = self.cov_params(r_matrix=r_matrix, cov_p=cov_p)
TypeError: cov_params() got an unexpected keyword argument 'r_matrix'
```

I also tried replace "hypothesis" above by

```
R=np.array([[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1]])
```

The same errors happen!

Comment: Did your estimation, `fit()`, converge? Did you get a warning that inverting hessian failed?

Comment: There is already a bug issue for this. So it looks like it's not directly possible. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/947

Comment: My estimation seems to converge! I did not realize any issue!

Comment: user333700 thank you! I did not know about this issue!

Comment: The new SARIMAX should have this working correctly, and has additionally several choices of covariance types including robust sandwich covariance. The problem in ARMA should be easy to fix (given there is demand for it).